# Why doesn't VS 2015 respect tsconfig exclude node_modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have an asp.net core app in that will not build because of dozens of Typescript errors on type definition files in node_modules. I have added

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```

to my tsconfig.json file, which resides in the root of the project, but Visual Studio doesn't seem to respect it.

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Better question: what errors are you getting? Let's find out why you're getting them. Knowing that might also help answer the original question as well.

Comment: I can't generate them right now because VS 2015 is in the middle of a multi-hour update, but they were mostly about not recognizing Promise and Map

Comment: Consider adding `"lib": ["dom", "es2015"]` to the `"compilerOptions"` field.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for this being a non-answer but i cannot yet comment.

Does project compile fine when you execute tsc from comand line in the tsconfig folder? If so this is an anyoying bug with msbuild that hasn't been fixed to this date (Typescript 2.0.3)

See here for more information https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7198

What I usually do is put my tsconfig and all typescript files and definitions in a sub-folder, so it cannot longer see the node_modules folder.
Worked for me.